Attacking noisy people who disturb meditation environment
When I am doing meditation, if people or neighbors are making noise or playing music, should I hit them hard and beat them ruthlessly? It's very disturbing and annoying.
Can I do violence without hatred and anger if someone is disturbing me by any means?

What do you mean by doing violence without hatred and anger? Please provide an example.

@chris defense force (army, intelligence etc.)

I’m voting to close this question because it makes me want to beat the question-asker ruthlessly.   j/k…

"@TedWrigley get lost asshole" - but as a joke!!

@BrendanDarrer: lol…

In one of his talks, Ajahn Chah once said,

If we understand that the sound bothers us then we suffer accordingly. If we investigate a little deeper, we will see that it's we who go out and disturb the sound!

When irritating sounds or noises impinged into our peaceful mind, it is an opportunity to see the culprit lurking behind the resulting aversion. Because behind every aversion is a hidden desire. Often, this desire hides itself behind a wall of righteous anger, human dignity, etiquette, and all sorts of excuses. If we don’t waver and get distracted but calmly observe our mind, in time we see through its disguise and identify the craving behind our irritation, anger and hate.
At this point, the desire may still insist there is nothing wrong with wanting peace and quietude. Then as it goes on and on, suddenly, an insight arises; it wasn’t the noise that was hurting us, it was the desire with its incessant demand and tyranny. That’s when the watchful part of our mind, the one called mindfulness begins to wonder, “Why am I causing so much suffering to myself? Why am I doing this to myself? What is wrong with me?”
Sometimes, we just have to experience the process firsthand as they say, “a picture paints a thousand words”. In this case, “an insight reveals true peace” i.e. it is not something others can take away from us instead we surrender it away.
can we do violence without hatred and anger if someone is disturbing me by any means?
Yes, if one is deluded. It will require one to ignore the fact that we are causing hurt with its consequences. Ultimately, resulting in retaliation and suffering. Likewise, when hatred and anger arise in our mind, we are already doing violence to ourselves. Extending hatred and anger to others is merely pouring more violence or hurt onto ourselves. Either way, the only people who will be happy in such situations will be our enemies.

I find this funny. But on serious note, Meditation on compassion is of the foremost importance. Meditation is not just a state of mind or what we constantly repeat in our mind but it should also reflect in our action. Buddha has said that if somebody cuts off your limbs while you are alive , you should not harbour any ill will towards them. Similarly if somebody disembowels you alive you should not harbour any ill will towards them. Similarly if somebody burns you alive you should not harbour any ill will towards them. If somebody drowns you alive you should not harbour any ill will towards them. And so on.
The point is you should not have any cruel thoughts no matter what the situation is. You should thank them for giving this important insight and move to a secluded place to do meditation. With every insight you should be moving away from the world to the point of no return in any form of existence.

violence without hatred and anger

It isn't the noise that disturbs you. It's your reaction to the noise that disturbs you. You have an expectation that your meditation time will be a time of quiet and peace, and when the world doesn't provide you with quiet and peace (like it damned well should!) you get miffed. But if you don't expect the world to provide you with quiet and peace, then you might actually find quiet and peace inside yourself, and then no external noise will disturb you.
I'm still contemplating how one might ruthlessly beat someone with metta and compassion…

If the noises are hindering your meditation, find a quieter place where noises don't bother you.
Use the noises as a reference on how good is your meditation. If your meditation is very good, noises should not bother you. This means that when people or neighbors are making noise or playing music, your meditation should be as good as in a quiet place. There shouldn't be any anger nor any other negative feelings. On the other hand, if your meditation is not that good, noises will bother you and different thoughts and feelings will arise.
There are cases when noises are so loud that it is a challenge to meditate. But even in such cases, if your meditation is very good, such loud noises would not bother you. They would bother the ears, but not you. It is indeed a challenge to meditate in such loud environment, so finding a quieter place is the right choice to do.
First become very good at meditation in quiet places. Once you develop enough insight and see and know the true cause of your thoughts and feelings, it would be easy to meditate even in loud environments if you choose to do so.

No, you shouldn't do that. Just move somewhere else where there is less noise or don't meditate at that time. You could also ask them not to play the music loud, as you are trying to meditate.
